# Show the location of the executable in GDB

Tags: linux, gdb

I suspect my gdb is accessing the wrong program location when I try to run it with "gdb [executable-name]". Is there anything I can do to have gdb output the location of the executable that's being debugged?

Comment: try `info file`.

Answer (score 1):

> I suspect my gdb is accessing the wrong program location when I try to run it with "gdb [executable-name]".

GDB will look for `./executable-name`, and then search `$PATH`.

GDB `info file` will tell you what binary it's currently using.

P.S. If in doubt, simply pass the absolute path to your binary explicitly: `gdb /path/to/executable-name`.